# Sort multidimensial array by date

Tags: php, date, multidimensional-array, sorting

I've tried this with usort, but I didn't succeed.
I've the following array:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        'date' => '3:6:2012'
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'date' => '5:5:2012'
    ),
    [2] => array(
        'date' => '20:12:2011'
    )
)
```

The date is in d:m:yyyy format, so no leading zero's.
I want to sort the array to get this:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        'date' => '20:12:2011'
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'date' => '5:5:2012'
    ),
    [2] => array(
        'date' => '3:6:2012'
    )
)
```

I've tried it this way:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if($a['date'] = $b['date']) {
        return 0;
    }
    $partsa = explode(":", $a['date']);
    $partsb = explode(":", $b['date']);
    $daya = $partsa[0];
    $montha = $partsa[1];
    $yeara = $partsa[2];
    $dayb = $partsb[0];
    $monthb = $partsb[1];
    $yearb = $partsb[2];
    if($yeara < $yearb) {
        return -1;
    } elseif($yeara > $yearb) {
        return 1;
    } elseif($yeara == $yearb) {
        if($montha < $monthb) {
            return -1;
        } elseif($montha > $monthb) {
            return 1;
        } elseif($montha == $monthb) {
            if($daya < $dayb) {
                return -1;
            } elseif($daya > $dayb) {
                return 1;
            } elseif($daya == $dayb) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't give good results with usort...
How to do this?

Comment: Well, first of all: `$a['date'] = $b['date']` should be `$a['date'] === $b['date']`

Comment: oops :P working now.. *me bad at debugging

Comment: This is still very wide and you should use date() instead dates stored as strings. That way, you can calculate easier with the values. See my answer, which takes less than half the lines of your code, and makes the values usable in other applications too :)

Answer (score 0):

First, make them dates (normal, php-readable dates):

```
foreach($array as $innerarray){
    foreach($innerarray as $key=>$value){
        $date = explode(":", $value);
        $date = date($date[2]."/".$date[1]."/".$date[0]);
        $array[$innerarray][$key] = $date;
    }
}
```

After this, you can sort them with the following function:

```
 function sort_bydate($a, $b) { 
     return strnatcmp($a['date'], $b['date']); 
 } 
 // sort by date 
 usort($data, 'sort_bydate');
```

This should do the trick.

By the way, I would advise to not use arrays in arrays, because it is useless in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary array with normalized dates (`yyyymmdd`), then use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'date' => '3:6:2012'
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '5:5:2012'
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '20:12:2011'
    ),
    array(
        'foo' => 'no date here'
    ),
);

foreach($arr as $key=>$row) {
    if(isset($row['date'])) {
        $date = explode(':',$row['date']);
        $date = $date[2] . str_pad($date[1],2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT) . str_pad($date[0],2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $sort_arr[$key] = $date;
    } else {
        $sort_arr[$key] = null;
    }
}
array_multisort($sort_arr, SORT_ASC, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP offers the function `strcmp`, that's doing the comparing stuff for us. In order to compare the dates correctly, we create timestamp out of it.

But at first we need to parse the string: exploding by `:` and finally throwing them to `mktime`.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a = explode(':', $a['date']);
    $a = mktime(0, 0, 0, intval($a[1]), intval($a[0]), intval($a[2]));

    $b = explode(':', $b['date']);
    $b = mktime(0, 0, 0, intval($b[1]), intval($b[0]), intval($b[2]));

    return strcmp($a, $b); 
}
```

Note: The first three arguments of `mktime` are hours, minutes and seconds and can be ignored in this scenario.